# Not In query not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run this query, it's supposed to get all employees who're not drivers in wh_route, the driver is a fk for

The following queries are working and giving me back results:

```
select distinct driver from wh_route;
select id from pa_employee o where o.id not in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

But when I try to do this:

```
select id from pa_employee o where o.id not in (select distinct driver from wh_route);
```

It doesn't return any results.

Tables for reference:

```
WH_ROUTE
id    driver
1     1
2     2

PA_EMPLOYEE
id
1
2
3
```

The expected behaviour is that it returns me the id 3, but it returns me nothing

Comment: You could add a null value to the sample data, to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` is somewhat tricky if the sub-query returns null values. Try `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
select id from pa_employee o
where o.id not exists (select * from wh_route where driver = o.id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D I added a check for null id's and it's working right now. Which one is more efficient though?

Comment: I don't know Oracle very well, but I find it hard to believe NOT EXISTS should be less efficient.

Comment: It is less efficient in the case where the `not in` set might contain nulls, because in order to handle that correctly the optimiser can't use the same straightforward approach it can use with `not exists` (or with a `not null` column).

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out: in the wh_route table there was a null value for driver, so the working query became

```
select id 
  from pa_employee o 
  where o.id not in (
    select distinct driver 
      from wh_route 
      where id is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to remove the DISTINCT in your sub-SELECT since it's not needed. That may speed up your query.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was not needed! :D It's removed now

Comment: No prob Bob :) .